# javascript class with event methods

Tags: javascript, class

My goal is to make a class with some chained functions, but I'm stuck and hoping for some help. This is what I got:

```
robin = new batman("myiv");
var batman = (function() {
    var me = this;
    function batman(id){
        me._id=id;
        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('mousemove', me.mouseMoving.bind(me),true);
    }
    this.mouseMoving = function(){
        document.getElementById(me._id).style.background="orange";
    }

    return batman;
}
```

And this pseudo code is what I am aiming to get. Basically, pass in the ID of an element in my HTML and chain functions to it such as onclick etc, and whatever code inside there, runs. as in example, changing background colors.

Is it possible?

```
superman("mydiv"){
    .onmouseover(){
        document.getElementById(the_id).style.background="#ffffff";
    },
    .onmouseout(){
        document.getElementById(the_id).style.background="#000000";
    },
    etc...
}
```

edit: updated with missing code: "return batman;"

Comment: Why not do this with CSS?

Comment: Those aren't really classes - they're object constructor functions

Comment: you need to return 'this' for chaining to happen

Comment: @tadman the background color changes are just for this example. I plan to put ajax calls etc within these events.

Comment: It's best to put in dummy code then instead of making it seem like all you're trying to do is change the background. Minimal code tries to focus on the problem without getting caught up in details.

Comment: I did write "as example, changing background colors", but I hear you. Would you be able to help me out with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do method chaining by returning the current object using **this** keyword

```
var YourClass = function () {
  this.items = [];
  this.push = function (item) {
    if (arguments) {
      this.items.push(item);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.count = function () {
    return this.items.length;
  }
}



var obj = new YourClass();
obj.push(1).push(1);
console.log(obj.count())
```

Working sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/method-chaining-example?file=index.js

Comment: thank you, this explains the chaining. But how would I be able to pass in code to/run as in my example, instead of the integers shown here? As im trying to set up events to run code.

Comment: @Jason do you want to send an anonymous method as an argument? I have added the stackblitz sample , I hope that you are expecting that. caller can decide what code need to be execute

Comment: I got it to work as i wanted, thanks for your help! :)